# Users should be able to flag tags for review

Tags: feature-request

Among my various rejected edits, one particularly stood out: the now-synonymized [sophont](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sophont) tag.

I was unable to suggest synonymization, so I did the next best thing: [edit the tag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/92375) to accurately reflect the term. I assume someone with privileges came along and synonymized it, and my edit got axed by the system in the process.

I don't think that the tag would have been synonymized without my intervention, and that's a problem. While I now realize that I could have either brought it up here on Meta, or in the site chat, being able to flag tags for review by more privileged users should probably be a feature. Alternatively, a way to propose synonymizations (and subsequently be reviewed) would solve the same problem.

---

**EDIT:**
I re-read the [relevant privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). I still think the ceiling to synonymize should be lowered-and flagging tags for review still feels like a good idea.

Comment: I don't know enough about tags to answer, though I do wonder at the wisdom of synonymising sophont --- which is a person --- and sapience, which is a property of persons. All persons are sophonts; not everything that is sapient is a person.

Comment: @elemtilas Perhaps the sapience tag should be renamed to sentience then. I do think that having `sophont` and `sapient` separate was too much categorization for this site

Comment: "Sentience" means possessing senses, or being able to perceive. Also, respond to stimuli and perception. Sapience means being able to reason, or capable of being intelligent, wise. It's the word we use to denote "intelligent humans": "Homo **Sapiens**". One can perceive the world without being able to reason. So - no, don't synonymise the two. And yes, I'm aware of crossover usage of "sentience", I still maintain this site shouldn't follow it but clearly separate the two concepts.

Comment: You're asking this question in the wrong place. Adjustments to privileges and new functionality requests belong on [meta.se] where (and I'll be COMPLETELY honest with you based on my own experience) you can expect little to no sympathy. We have absolutely no ability to do anything about what you're asking from here. (Unless what you're asking is *specifically* to reverse the synonymization and reinstate your edits for that specific tag. That, we can do (with a moderator's help).

Comment: @JBH I'd noticed that privileges were different across a few stacks; for example, on 3D Printing, [close and reopen privileges are granted at 500 rep](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), rather than the 2.5k we have  here. I assumed this was something moderators could change.

Comment: @TheCommander It may be that it is - but I would disagree with a request to change it. One of the many difficulties with [worldbuilding.se] is that, as a creative and imaginative resource, it's painfully difficult to rationally and consistently close and reopen questions. On sites where the intent of the site is comparatively black-and-white a low rep reflects the ease with which users come to grips with the rules. Here, it can be difficult after years of experience. Frankly, it's desirable here that users gain considerable experience before exposure to that authority.

Answer (score -1):

This is working as intended: Synonimized tags can't have a description on their own.

Comment: I don't see how saying synonimized tags can't have a description is an answer to "Users should be able to flag tags for review". The Commander is more concerned about having their edit and/or synonimi... Sinino... that action easily notified to other members of the community.